# org-mode macro not evaluated inside link?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

If I create a file with `{{{input-file}}}` as contents and export to HTML, the default macro is correctly evaluated to the filename. However, if I write `[[file:{{{input-file}}}.alternative][Alternative version]]` the macro is *not* evaluated. However, if I place the macro on the other part of the link: `[[file:manual.html.alternative][{{{input-file}}}.alternative]]` then it works!
If I use it in a `#+BEGIN_HTML #+END_HTML` session instead of in a link the macro isn't evaluated either.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Damn it, org-mode. I can't believe you named another feature "macro" when that term was *already* overloaded in Emacs. I've edited the title to make it less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `emacs-lisp` `src` block with raw results.

For example:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports results :results raw
(concat "[[file:./" (buffer-file-name) ".alternative]]" )
#+end_src
```

To get rid of confirmation messages, you can use the `org-confirm-babel-evaluate`variable. This is my setting:

```
    (defun my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate (lang body)
       (not (member lang '("dot" "emacs-lisp" "shell" "plantuml"))))
    (setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate 'my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate)
```